# Python equivalent of "library(help = PackageName)" and "?FunctionName" (i.e. help() function) from R

Tags: python, r

There are many handy functions in R, but the two most handy functions I found were

```
library(help = dplyr) 
?data.frame
# So the library(help = PackageName) & ?FunctionName
```

Are there similar tools in Python I can make use of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help).

```py
>>> import pandas
>>> help(pandas)
```

```
Help on package pandas:

NAME
    pandas

DESCRIPTION
    pandas - a powerful data analysis and manipulation library for Python
    =====================================================================

    **pandas** is a Python package providing fast, flexible, and expressive data
    structures designed to make working with "relational" or "labeled" data both...
```

Or, if you want to know for a specific function/class as oppose to a module:

```py
>>> import pandas
>>> help(pandas.DataFrame)
```

```
class DataFrame(pandas.core.generic.NDFrame)
 |  DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
 |
 |  Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data
 |  structure with labeled axes (rows and columns). Arithmetic operations
 |  align on both row and column labels. Can be thought of as a dict-like
 |  container for Series objects. The primary pandas data structure.
 |
 |  Parameters
 |  ----------
 |  data : ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame
 |      Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, or list-like objects
...
```

```py
>>> import pandas
>>> help(pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)
```

```
Help on function to_csv in module pandas.core.generic:

to_csv(self, path_or_buf=None, sep=',', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, compression='infer', quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator=None, chunksize=None, date_format=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal='.')
    Write object to a comma-separated values (csv) file.

    .. versionchanged:: 0.24.0
        The order of arguments for Series was changed.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path_or_buf : str or file handle, default None
        File path or object, if None is provided the result is returned as
        a string.  If a file object is passed it should be opened with
        `newline=''`, disabling universal newlines.
....
```